# How to pass audio from a Docker container through NoMachine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, remote-access, audio-streaming, nomachine

My setup involves an Ubuntu machine (computer A) and a Mac (computer B). They are on two different networks but are accessible through VPN. On computer A, I can use Docker compose to launch a container that outputs audio, which I can also hear on computer A. If I use computer B to remote desktop using NoMachine into computer A and run the same docker compose command, I get an "ALSA: device or resource is busy". This is because the NoMachine client is already using the ALSA client so my Docker container can't access it. How can I resolve this issue so I can pass audio to computer B?

My docker-compose.yml, which works locally, includes:

```
volumes:
    - /dev/snd:/dev/snd
    - (other volumes)
devices:
    - /dev/snd:/dev/snd
```